# IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: Text, received LongWritable

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I understand that this topic has been discussed in the past. But I unfortunately have not been able to resolve the issue. I keep getting the same IOException error. I am very new to Java & Hadoop and this is my first attempt to WordCount exercise. I apologize for any syntax errors or format issues. please let me know where I am going wrong.

> Error: java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key
>   from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Here is my code:

```
MyDriver

package p1;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class MyDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        // Create a configuration class pointing to default configuration
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        // Create an object of Job by specifying conf object
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "MyWordCountJob");

        // Link your Driver Class with the Job
        job.setJarByClass(MyDriver.class);

        // Link your Mapper Class with the Job
        job.setJarByClass(MyMapper.class);

        // Link your Reducer Class with the Job
        job.setJarByClass(MyReducer.class);

        // set final output Key
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

        // set final output Value
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        // Defining input Paths
        Path input_dir = new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/input_data/");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input_dir);

        // Defining Output Paths
        Path output_dir = new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/output_data/");
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output_dir);

        // This piece of code will actually initiate the Job run
        // boolean flag = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println("is this running");

        // system.exit means it will kill the jvm and terminate the program.
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        System.out.println("job.waitForCompletion(true)"
                + job.waitForCompletion(true));

    }
}

package p1;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String currentline = line.toString();
        System.out.println("MyMapper.map():Offset" + offset
                + " :: CurrentLine=" + currentline);

        // apple apple ball--this is read when the mapper reads the data for the
        // first time/ mapper reads line by line.
        System.out.println(currentline);
        String words[] = currentline.split(" ");

        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(" words " + word);
            context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
}

MyReducer

package p1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    //apple [1,1,1]

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text word, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context ctx)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Key=" + word);

        Iterator<IntWritable> it = value.iterator();

        int count = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            IntWritable i = (IntWritable) it.next();
            count = count + i.get();
        }

        ctx.write(word, new IntWritable(count));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it breaking on the map phase or the reduce phase?

Comment: it is breaking on the map phase. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a sample line from the input file the mapper is reading?

Comment: Here is the first line in the input file "apple apple apple"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
```

instead of

```
job.setJarByClass(MyMapper.class);
job.setJarByClass(MyReducer.class);
```

Comment: @zoheb if this resolution fix your problem, could you please accept it

Comment: Thanks Shalaj. The issue got resolved. I was able to get the desired output. Can you please let me know when setJarByClass should be used.

Comment: setJarByClass used to set your driver class only, in your case  job.setJarByClass(MyDriver.class); please accept this answer by clicking on tick icon

Comment: Thank you Shalaj.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a typechecking problem on your Map key (In almost every practical case, you won't need to tinker with the key type at the map stage).  Try this:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void map(Object offset, Text line, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I made the suggested changes. But I continue to get the same error. :(

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace you're getting into the question section?

Comment: Paul, the issue got resolved by replacing setJarByClass. would you still be interested in seeing the stack trace??